# horizontally center asp menu

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am unable to centre the menu bar horizontally. The no. of main menu items may inc./Dec. with each user login. This code makes the menu bar start at like 30% from the left.
Tried display:inline-block and display:table for #menuContainer.

If there are 5 main menu items and I set the width of #menuContainer to 30%, it appears centred.

ASPX:

```
<div id="divMenu">
 <div id="menuContainer">
  <asp:Menu id ="menuBar" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
   IncludeStyleBlock="false">
    <item>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Folio">
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Nature"></asp:MenuItem>
       <asp:MenuItem Text="People">
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Tribe"></asp:MenuItem>
       </asp:MenuItem>    
     </asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact"></asp:MenuItem>
    </items>
   </asp:Menu>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#divMenu
{
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:7%;
z-index:2;
width:100%;
height:5%;
}
#menuContainer
{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#menuBar
{
 position:fixed;
 top:5.3%;
}
#menuBar ul
{
list-style:none;
background-color:silver;
padding:0 5px;
}
```

RENDERED HTML:

```
<div id="divMenu">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <a href="#menuBar_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/..sometext"   
     width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
    <div id="menuBar">
      <ul class="level1">
         <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="...">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="popout level1" href="#" onclick="..">Folio</a>
             <ul class="level2">
                <li><a class="level2" href="#" href="#" onclick="..">Nature</a></li>
                <li><a class="level2" href="#" href="#" onclick="..">People</a>
                  <ul class="level3">
                   <li><a class="level3" href="#" onclick="..">Tribe</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="...">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div><a id="menuBar_Skiplink"</a></div></div>
```

Comment: what happens if you remove styling from `#menuBar`?

Comment: It moves its position towards the bottom, like 20 px. That styling makes it stay inside the #divMenu exactly.

Comment: It's staying because of the `fixed` position. Add the rendered html as well(not asp one).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cck3V/

```
<div id="divMenu">
 <div class="menuContainer">
         <a>Item 1</a>
         <a>Item 2</a>
  </div><br><br>
 <div class="menuContainer">
         <a>Item 1</a>
         <a>Item 2</a>
         <a>Item 3</a>
  </div><br><br>
 <div class="menuContainer">
         <a>Item 1</a>
         <a>Item 2</a>
         <a>Item 3</a>
         <a>Item 4</a>
  </div><br><br>
 </div>
```

-

```
-- css --
#divMenu {position:fixed;text-align:center;left:0;right:0;top:7%;z-index:2;height:5%;}
.menuContainer {display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;background-color:silver;text-align:left;clear:both;}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:left;` this centers the div containing menu, also parent element should have `text-align:center` or `<center>`

Comment: Yes I understand margin:0 auto. But thats what happened :(

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` works when width is defined, if you need width to be auto, add `display:inline-block;`, also parent element should have `text-align:center` or `<center>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43412/discussion-between-atul-gupta-and-ruby)